Load a TensorFlow model trained on Windows Native environment to Windows WSL2 (Linux Ubuntu)
I have a TensorFlow functional model, model, that accepts two sets of inputs (time series and regular features) and produces the probabilities for 3 different classes. I trained this model on Windows Native environment. After the training, I saved the model to my local storage.
model.save("trained_model.h5")

Then, on Windows WSL2 environment, which runs Linux Ubuntu, I tried to load the model using load_model()
import tensorflow as tf

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained_model.h5")

However, it gives me this error.
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']

I am using tensorflow '2.17.0' on both environments.
I am working on a laptop which has NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU.
I also tried saving the model in keras format (i.e., trained_model.keras) or even using pickle to port the model. Both unsuccessful.
Does anyone can shed light on how to fix this issue or suggest an alternative method to port the model from Windows Native to Windows WSL2 environment?

The batch_shape error might be related to how the input shapes are specified in the model. Ensure the portability of your model's input layers by specifying the correct batch_shape or input_shape. If the issue still persists, please provide more details about model's architecture.
